# prove that two determinants contain the the same set of roots when solving system of linear differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra

[I am trying to solve an execrise from my textbook and can't figure out what should I do for the last step]

---

**[Problem]** Find the expression of general solution of the following system of linear differential equations
(the $^{(i)}$ denotes differentiation with respect to $t$, all terms are non-zero)
$$\begin{cases}x^{(1)}=y-z+w\\y^{(1)}=x+z+w\\z^{(1)}=x-y+w\\w^{(1)}=x-y-2z\end{cases}$$

---

**[What I got so far]**

[Section 1]

[Step 1.1]: I should look for solutions with the following form
$$x=b_1e^{\lambda t},\ y=b_2e^{\lambda t},\ z=b_3e^{\lambda t},\ w=b_4e^{\lambda t}$$
[Step 1.2]:
$$
\begin{cases}x^{(1)}=0\cdot x+y-z+w\\y^{(1)}=x+0\cdot y+z+w\\z^{(1)}=x-y+0\cdot z+w\\w^{(1)}=x-y-2z+0\cdot w\end{cases}
\to
\begin{cases}b_1\lambda e^{\lambda t}=0\cdot b_1e^{\lambda t}+b_2e^{\lambda t}-b_3e^{\lambda t}+b_4e^{\lambda t}\\b_2\lambda e^{\lambda t}=b_1e^{\lambda t}+0\cdot b_2e^{\lambda t}+b_3e^{\lambda t}+b_4e^{\lambda t}\\b_3\lambda e^{\lambda t}=b_1e^{\lambda t}-b_2e^{\lambda t}+0\cdot b_3e^{\lambda t}+b_4e^{\lambda t}\\b_4\lambda e^{\lambda t}=b_1e^{\lambda t}-b_2e^{\lambda t}-2b_3e^{\lambda t}+0\cdot b_4e^{\lambda t}\end{cases}
\to
\begin{cases}-\lambda b_1+b_2-b_3+b_4=0\\\ \ \ b_1-\lambda b_2+b_3+b_4=0\\\ \ \ b_1-b_2-\lambda b_3+b_4=0\\\ b_1-b_2-2b_3-\lambda b_4=0\end{cases}
$$
[Step 1.3]: Because $b_1,\ b_2,\ b_3,\ b_4$ are non-zero, so
$$D_1=\begin{vmatrix}-\lambda&1&-1&1\\1&-\lambda&1&1\\1&-1&-\lambda&1\\1&-1&-2&-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=0$$

########################################################

[Section 2]

[Step 2.1]: Let $\xi=x$, then
$$
\begin{cases}\xi=x\\\xi^{(1)}=x^{(1)}=y-z+w\\\xi^{(2)}=y^{(1)}-z^{(1)}+w^{(1)}=x-z\\\xi^{(3)}=x^{(1)}-z^{(1)}=-x+2y+z+w\\\xi^{(4)}=-x^{(1)}+2y^{(1)}+z^{(1)}+w^{(1)}=4x-3y-2w\end{cases}
\to
\begin{cases}\begin{align}-\xi+x+0\cdot y+0\cdot z+0\cdot w=0\\-\xi^{(1)}+0\cdot x+y-z+w=0\\-\xi^{(2)}+x+0\cdot y-z+0\cdot w=0\\-\xi^{(3)}-x+2y+z+w=0\\-\xi^{(4)}+4x-3y+\cdot z-2w=0\end{align}\end{cases}
$$

[Step 2.2]: Because $x,\ y,\ z,\ w$ are non-zero, then
$$\begin{vmatrix}-\xi&1&0&0&0\\-\xi^{(1)}&0&1&-1&1\\-\xi^{(2)}&1&0&-1&0\\-\xi^{(3)}&-1&2&1&1\\-\xi^{(4)}&4&-3&0&-2\end{vmatrix}=0$$

[Step 2.3] now look for a solution in the form $\xi=Ce^{\sigma t}$, then
$$
\begin{vmatrix}-Ce^{\sigma t}&1&0&0&0\\-\sigma Ce^{\sigma t}&0&1&-1&1\\-\sigma^2 Ce^{\sigma t}&1&0&-1&0\\-\sigma^3 Ce^{\sigma t}&-1&2&1&1\\-\sigma^4 Ce^{\sigma t}&4&-3&0&-2\end{vmatrix}=0
$$

[Step 2.4] from the above determinant, I can get
$$
D_2=\begin{vmatrix}1&1&0&0&0\\\sigma&0&1&-1&1\\\sigma^2&1&0&-1&0\\\sigma^3&-1&2&1&1\\\sigma^4&4&-3&0&-2\end{vmatrix}=0
$$

---

**[Question]:** From the above steps I get the two determinant
$$D_1=\begin{vmatrix}-\lambda&1&-1&1\\1&-\lambda&1&1\\1&-1&-\lambda&1\\1&-1&-2&-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=0\\D_2=\begin{vmatrix}1&1&0&0&0\\\sigma&0&1&-1&1\\\sigma^2&1&0&-1&0\\\sigma^3&-1&2&1&1\\\sigma^4&4&-3&0&-2\end{vmatrix}=0$$
I want to show that the roots of $D_2$ (values of $\sigma$) are the same as the roots of $D_1$ (values of $\lambda$) so that I can solve $D_2$ instead of directly dealing with $D_1$.

How am I suppose the prove the equivalence of roots of the two determinants ?

Comment: Hint: Consider the issue under the form $X'=MX$, and take the diagonalized form of $M$ (the eigenvalues of matrix $M$ are $\pm 1$ and $\pm 2i$).

Comment: @JeanMarie, Thanks for the hint, but I cant understand it because I am only two chapters into the book...... and things like eigenvalues, transformation are in the later chapters...... Should I go read these things first before coming back to this problem ?

Comment: These techniques bring such a simplification that I think it's worth the value to go ahead and assimilate them, especially with a $4 \times 4 system like this one which is hardly tractable "by hand".